# Логическая задача на поиск соответствия

Tags: математика, логика

Константин, Дмитрий, Михаил и Сергей - жители нашего города. Их профессии - повар, водитель, инструктор по плаванию и милиционер. Константин и Дмитрий - соседи и каждый день на работу ездят вместе. Дмитрий старше Михаила. Константин регулярно обыгрывает Сергея в шахматы. Повар на работу всегда ходит пешком. Милиционер не живет рядом с водителем. Инструктор и милиционер встречались единственный раз, когда милиционер оштрафовал инструктора по плаванию за нарушение правил дорожного движения. Милиционер старше водителя и инструктора.

Вопрос. Кто чем из четырех человек, живущих в городе, занимается?

Уже понял, что Дмитрий - милиционер.

Comment: @rberla, Перевели бы вы на русский вашу задачку.

Comment: А теперь, пожалуйста, сделайте вопрос в соответствии, хотя бы, с основным языком сайта.   
*Подсказка: русский.

Comment: я задачу понял =) но нафига она тут? ты типа решил когото пригрузить?))

Comment: Он перепутал четверг и пятницу. =)
P.S. я задачу понял// А мне лень. Либо английский, либо русский.

Comment: На первый взгляд, какая-то упрощенная версия [задачи Эйнштейна](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%AD%D0%B9%D0%BD%D1%88%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%B0)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Повар ходит пешком - значит, он Сергей или Михаил. Мент не живет рядом с водилой, и видел инструктора лишь раз, => мент - либо Сергей, либо Михаил. Кто-то из водилы и инструктора - Константин и Дмитрий. Дмитрий старше Михаила, однако мент старше Дмитрия, следовательно, повар - Михаил. Мент, стало быть, Сергей, и он лишь раз виделся с инструктором Дмитрием, так как с Константином все время играет в шахматы.
Итак, повар - Михаил, водитель - Константин, инструктор - Дмитрий, мент - Сергей.